# Why does EF say an object with the same key already exists when it's "Detached"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

In my repository update method, I first attach existing objects that may need to be added to the updated entity's collections before doing anything else, so that EF realizes that I want to associate the entity with another existing entity, and not create a new one.  So in this example, I'm doing it with user groups:

```
UserGroup basicGroup = repoGroup.GetGroupByName("BasicGroup");
List<UserGroup> updatedGroups = new List<UserGroup> { basicGroup };
foreach (var user in usersToUpdate) {
    repoUser.UpdateUser(user.userId, updatedGroups);
}

[...]

public bool UpdateUser(int updatedUserId, List<UserGroup> updatedGroups) {
    using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
        if (updatedGroups != null) {
            // Attach groups to context before add so that EF creates a new
            // relationship between entity and new items in groups collection,
            // instead of creating a new entity for each new item.
            foreach (UserGroup group in updatedGroups) {

                var testEntry = context.Entry(group);

                context.UserGroups.Attach(group);
            }
        }

        var userToUpdate = context.Users.First(usr => usr.id == updatedUserId);
        userToUpdate.UserGroups.Clear();
        foreach (var group in updatedGroups) {
            userToUpdate.UserGroups.Add(group);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
}
```

So my code cycles through several users and tries to associate a new set of groups with them.  I realize the mistake I'm making here is that my `.Attach` is potentially trying to attach the same entity to the object context twice - in this case, `basicGroup`.  So I thought I could test to see whether the object had already been attached and only attach it if it hadn't.

So look at the testEntry line.  There, I try and get the `group` entity's `Entry` status.  I do indeed get a `DbEntityEntry` instance, but it always says that the `EntityState` is `Detached` (in every loop iteration).  Now, when I run my code, it's OK in the first iteration of the foreach loop, but in the second iteration, I get the exception:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I don't understand this; if the object already exists in the ObjectStateManager, why does my `DbEntityEntry` say its state is `Detached`?  Surely it should remember that its state is `Unchanged`.

Comment: What's the key of the detached Entries? Is it set? Or is it unset in every case?

Comment: @Grumbler85 How do you determine the key?

Comment: The key is probably the primary key in the database table. In most cases it will be something like `GroupId` for a class/table named `group`. The ObjectStateManager uses the same.

Comment: @Grumbler85 Well I used `((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(testEntry.Entity)` and the first time round, `EntityKey` was `EntitySet=UserGroups;GroupId=1`.  However, because this was only available *after* the `Attach` method was called, I couldn't get it the second time round because the exception is thrown when `Attach` is called.

Comment: But the group in the "second round" should have a property called GroupId, right? And if that is 1, too, than there's a problem...

Comment: Btw. is you updatedGroups distinct?

Comment: Just saw something: If you use `using(var context ...)` your Entites will never show that they are attached, because they are not attached to *that specific context*

Comment: @Grumbler85 OK, but each context has a `ObjectStateManager` attached to it, and the second time round, it is saying that an object with the same key exists in it.  If the Entity is not attached to that context, then why does that context's `ObjectStateManager` say that it contains an object with that Entity's key?

Comment: There is an object, which was on another context and has the same key. Initialize the context in your outer function and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue not so long ago, and it was basically the compiler telling you that, within your context, you have an entity loaded into memory, which then you're trying to attach back to the same context (the second forloop iteration - the objects being attached are on that initial context).

To fix the problem, for the .Add method, use a separate context (a new "using" call), and this will work. That's the only workaround I could find.

i.e. (my UnitOfWork = your normal context)

```
UnitOfWork _context = new UnitOfWork();

// Add 1
_context.Add(obj);

using(UnitOfWork context = new UnitOfWork()){
   // Do second addition routines here based on objects used in add 1.
   context.Add(childobj);
   context.SaveChanges();
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am using a new "using" call for each iteration.  My code calls `UpdateUser` each time and each `UpdateUser` call runs code in its own `using` block.

Comment: Yep, but within this using block, you're attaching a child object to the context and then using this object in the next forloop, when it's already been added to that context. You need to use two seperate usings, one for the first addition, and another for the second.